# Oracle date format for specific data

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a t1 table having column name  month 
I have a month  column having data format 
December , 2017 want to convert it into first day of that specific month.

Comment: Don't store your dates as text.  Please edit your question and show sample data.

Comment: Is that the **exact** format, with a space before the comma and another space after it? Then: Define "convert". Do you want to populate another column in the same table, this one having the correct data type of `DATE`? Do you just want to "convert" in a `select` query? Or what else?

Comment: Yes I have space before comma yes want to convert in select query

Comment: Assuming the month names are always in English (and valid), will all sessions that could run your code always also be in English? If you aren't sure then your can [specify a date language in the `to_date()` call](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_DATE.html) to override the session settings..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the input is a string like `'December , 2017'` - perhaps in a column named `mth` (best if it's not called `month`, because that is an Oracle keyword), the easiest way to get the first of the month, in the `date` data type, is

```
to_date(mth, 'Month , yyyy')
```

This is because if the day of the month is not provided, the default is the first day.

Demo:

```
select to_date('December , 2017', 'Month , yyyy') as first_of_mth from dual;

FIRST_OF_MTH      
-------------------
2017-12-01 00:00:00
```